# Is it valid to use "attribute" in any tag, that is not specified by w3

Tags: facebook, w3c-validation

I just noticed that FACEBOOK is using "ajaxify" attribute in thein `<a>` tag.

- Is it valid to use the attribute that is not specified by the W3
  standards?
- Will it be validated?
- Can we you any custom attribute like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless something has changed with the new html5 stuff, no this is not valid.  However, browsers usually don't care either way and javascript will be able to find these new attrs.

That being said... Here's what the spec (xhtml 1.0) has to say:

(from http://www.w3.org/TR/html/#uaconf)
"If a user agent encounters an attribute it does not recognize, it must ignore the entire attribute specification (i.e., the attribute and its value)."